# PyGame adding more pictures/cannot get it to display the different "coin" images seperately

Tags: pygame

```
    import pygame, random

    pygame.init()

    # create a display surface
    WINDOW_WIDTH=600
    WINDOW_HEIGHT=300
    display_surface = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOW_WIDTH,WINDOW_HEIGHT))

    # set FPS and clock, 
    # for example clock.tick(40) means that for every second at most 40 frames should pass.
    FPS = 10
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # set the games values
    VELOCITY = 5

    # load images
    dragon_image = pygame.image.load("dragon_right.png")
    dragon_rect = dragon_image.get_rect()
    dragon_rect.topleft = (25,25)

    coin_image = pygame.image.load("coin.png")
    coin_rect = coin_image.get_rect()
    coin_rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2,WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)

    coin_image = pygame.image.load("coin_green.png")
    coin_rect = coin_image.get_rect()
    coin_rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2,WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)

    coin_image = pygame.image.load("coin_blue.png")
    coin_rect = coin_image.get_rect()
    coin_rect.center = (WINDOW_WIDTH//2,WINDOW_HEIGHT//2)

    #I need to add a rotating elipse here

    # the main game loop 
    running = True
    while running:
    # process each update

    # listen for quit request
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #get keys to see who is pressed down
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and dragon_rect.left > 0:
         dragon_rect.x -= VELOCITY
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and dragon_rect.right < WINDOW_WIDTH:
            dragon_rect.x += VELOCITY

    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and dragon_rect.top > 0:
         dragon_rect.y -= VELOCITY
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and dragon_rect.bottom < WINDOW_HEIGHT:
            dragon_rect.y += VELOCITY

    # check for collison of the two objects
    if dragon_rect.colliderect(coin_rect):
         print('HIT')
         coin_rect.x = random.randint(0, WINDOW_WIDTH - coin_image.get_width())
         coin_rect.y = random.randint(0, WINDOW_HEIGHT - coin_image.get_height())

    # fill display surface 
    display_surface.fill((0,0,0))
    
    #  draw boundaries 
    pygame.draw.rect(display_surface, (0,255,0), dragon_rect, 1)
    pygame.draw.rect(display_surface, (255,255,0), coin_rect, 1)

    # blit assets
    display_surface.blit(dragon_image,dragon_rect)
    display_surface.blit(coin_image, coin_rect)
    display_surface.blit(coin_image, coin_rect)

    #update display 
    pygame.display.update()

    # tick the clock
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

I added the call to display my pictures but it only ever displays the last one coded. In this case "coin_blue".I need to get it to display all the different coins as well as a rotating elipse and assign each coin point values (1,2,3, and 4). I also need to change the background to a starfield so if you could help with that as well it would be much appreciated.